# Countring occurences of strings in a list even if the string is reversed

Tags: python, list, reverse

I have a list of letter-pairs whose occurences I need to count in a next step but their reverses are considered the same thing, so 'mo' and 'om' would be 2 occurences of 'mo' and so on -
i figured I would transform the list of strings into a list where I reversed the strings and then counted their occurences so this list so I can have a dictionary with how often they occur:

```
pairs = ['mo', 'om', 'mo', 'om', 'ab', 'ba', 'ab', 'ba', 'ab', 'af', 'fa', 'fa', 'fa']
counted_pairs = [pairs.count(i) for i in pairs]
my_dictionary = dict(zip(pairs,counted_pairs))
```

Should be transformed into this:

```
pairs = ['mo', 'mo', 'mo', 'mo', 'ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'af', 'af', 'af', 'af']
counted_pairs = [pairs.count(i) for i in pairs]
my_dictionary = dict(zip(pairs,counted_pairs))
```

in order for me to count them.

I came up with this code:

```
pairs = ['mo', 'om', 'mo', 'om', 'ab', 'ba', 'ab', 'ba', 'ab', 'af', 'fa', 'fa', 'fa']
loop_pairs = []

for i in range(0,len(pairs)):
    word = pairs[i]
    for el in range(0,len(pairs)):
        if word == pairs[el]:
            loop_pairs.append(pairs[el])
        else:
            if word == pairs[el][::-1]:
                loop_pairs.append(pairs[el][::-1])
```

and it works in so far that it appends the reversed pairs to the new list, but I would then need to delete the rest of the occurences because it goes on to then examine the next object and since I already counted that in the first round of the outer loop this is not what I need anymore.

I hope this is clear, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just sort each pair into a consistent order before counting:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> pairs = ['mo', 'om', 'mo', 'om', 'ab', 'ba', 'ab', 'ba', 'ab', 'af', 'fa', 'fa', 'fa']
>>> counts = Counter("".join(sorted(p)) for p in pairs)
>>> counts
Counter({'ab': 5, 'mo': 4, 'af': 4})
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using a library?

Comment: @Eva `collections.Counter` is in the standard library.

Comment: Yes but I still am not allowed to use any libraries, sorry i should have clarified this